# Downloading, Saving and previewing image on JOptionPane

Tags: java, cmd, joptionpane, javax.imageio

I am creating a modern command-line application, it takes command and gives values, I have created many commands, the thing I need to know is how I can download an image from the internet, save it in a file, then preview that image on `JOptionPane`(`JFrame`), as for a virtual code, I want this to happen:

```
// REGULAR JAVA:
String link = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter The Link of the image:");
String directoryToBeSavedIn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter directory");
// What I need:
saveImage(link, directoryToBeSavedInAndName); // Download and save( e.g. C:\Down.png )
Image downloadedImage = new Image(directoryToBeSavedInAndName); // Specifies an Image type object, that is the downloaded Image
JOptionPane.showPicture(downloadedImage); // this calls the JOptionPane, with showPicture as a panel that will show a picture to the user.
```

Unreal Codes:
`saveImage();`***,*** `Image .. = new Image();`***,*** `showPicture();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this class you have (at least) two ways to display the image:

```
public static class PictureView extends JFrame {

    public PictureView(ImageIcon image) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel labelImage = new JLabel(image);
        panel.add(labelImage);
        setContentPane(panel);
    }

}
```

(1) Directly without downloading to your filesystem:

```
    try {
        URL imageUrl = new URL("http://domain/oneimage.png"); // your URL or link
        PictureView view = new PictureView(new ImageIcon(imageUrl));
        view.pack();
        view.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

(2) Or by downloading first:

```
    try {
        URL imageUrl = new URL("http://domain/anotherimage.png"); // your URL or link
        InputStream in = imageUrl.openStream();
        Path outputPath = Paths.get("downloaded.png"); // your directoryToBeSavedInAndName
        Files.copy(in, outputPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        PictureView view = new PictureView(new ImageIcon("downloaded.png"));  // your directoryToBeSavedInAndName
        view.pack();
        view.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```